# Populating 2d array zig zag with consecutive numbers C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm stuck on this. Could you please help me?

Write   a   function    which   initialize  a   two-dimensional array.  The array   is  a square
matrix  (i.e.,  its width   and height  are identical.) The array   should  be  initialized in  the 
zig-zag style.  Specifically,   we  start   at  the top-left    corner  and go  downward,   and put a
number  starting from   1.  Once    we  hit the bottom, we  go  to  the next    column  and fill    in
the numbers from    bottom  to  top.    We  fill    the numbers downward    in  the third
column, upward  in  the fourth  column, and so  on. The process ends when   all the 
elements    in  the array   are filled.

```
However, How do I get my output like this?
1 10 11 20 21
2 9 12 19 22
3 8 13 18 23
4 7 14 17 24
5 6 15 16 25

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int SIZE = 5; // Note SIZE can be anything between 1 to 9
void initGrid(int grid[SIZE][SIZE]);
void printGrid(int grid[SIZE][SIZE]);
int main() {
    int grid[SIZE][SIZE];
    initGrid(grid);
    printGrid(grid);
}
void initGrid(int grid[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    int inc = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
             grid[i][j] = inc;
             inc++;
        }
    }
}
void printGrid(int grid[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            // setw() function handles the printing format.
            cout << setw(2) << grid[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every two columns of the grid share the same filling pattern, the odd ones are filled in ascending order, the even ones in descending order. All you have to do is translate that into code:

```
template<size_t Rows, size_t Cols>
void initGrid(int (&grid)[Rows][Cols]) {
    int value = 1;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < Cols; ++j) {
        // first fill the odd column in descending order
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Rows; ++i, ++value) {
            grid[i][j] = value;
        }
        // then, if there is one, fill the even column
        ++j;
        if (j == Cols )
            break;
        for (size_t i = Rows; i > 0; ++value) {
            --i;   // size_t is unsigned, so I have to check i before decrementing
            grid[i][j] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I used the same data structure you used (but a different function signature) only to focus on the algorithm, but I'd use a class instead.

If you don't want to traverse the array column-wise (which, for *big* arrays, could result in performance drop due to cache misses) you can calculate the differences between values in every row:

```
template<size_t Rows, size_t Cols>
void zig_zag_fill(int (&grid)[Rows][Cols])
{
    int diff_up = 1;
    int diff_down = Rows * 2 - 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Rows; ++i, diff_down -= 2, diff_up += 2)
    {
        int value = i + 1;
        size_t j = 0;
        while ( j < Cols )
        {
            grid[i][j] = value;
            value += diff_down;
            ++j;
            if ( j == Cols )
                break;
            grid[i][j] = value;
            value += diff_up;
            ++j;
        }
    }
}
```

A complete test program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template<size_t Rows, size_t Cols>
void zig_zag_fill(int (&grid)[Rows][Cols]);

template<size_t Rows, size_t Cols>
void printGrid(int (&grid)[Rows][Cols]);

int main() {
    int grid[5][6];
    zig_zag_fill(grid);
    printGrid(grid);
    std::cout << '\n';
    int grid2[6][5];
    zig_zag_fill(grid2);
    printGrid(grid2);
    std::cout << '\n';
    int grid3[5][5];
    zig_zag_fill(grid3);
    printGrid(grid3);
    std::cout << '\n';
    int grid4[6][6];
    zig_zag_fill(grid4);
    printGrid(grid4);
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template<size_t Rows, size_t Cols>
void initGrid(int (&grid)[Rows][Cols]) {
    int value = 1;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < Cols; ++j) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Rows; ++i, ++value) {
            grid[i][j] = value;
        }
        ++j;
        if (j == Cols )
            break;
        for (size_t i = Rows; i > 0; ++value) {
            --i;
            grid[i][j] = value;
        }
    }
}

template<size_t Rows, size_t Cols>
void zig_zag_fill(int (&grid)[Rows][Cols])
{
    int diff_up = 1;
    int diff_down = Rows * 2 - 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Rows; ++i, diff_down -= 2, diff_up += 2)
    {
        int value = i + 1;
        size_t j = 0;
        while ( j < Cols )
        {
            grid[i][j] = value;
            value += diff_down;
            ++j;
            if ( j == Cols )
                break;
            grid[i][j] = value;
            value += diff_up;
            ++j;
        }
    }
}


template<size_t Rows, size_t Cols>
void printGrid(int (&grid)[Rows][Cols]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Rows; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < Cols; ++j) {
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << grid[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Would output:

```
 1 10 11 20 21 30 
 2  9 12 19 22 29 
 3  8 13 18 23 28 
 4  7 14 17 24 27 
 5  6 15 16 25 26 

 1 12 13 24 25 
 2 11 14 23 26 
 3 10 15 22 27 
 4  9 16 21 28 
 5  8 17 20 29 
 6  7 18 19 30 

 1 10 11 20 21 
 2  9 12 19 22 
 3  8 13 18 23 
 4  7 14 17 24 
 5  6 15 16 25 

 1 12 13 24 25 36 
 2 11 14 23 26 35 
 3 10 15 22 27 34 
 4  9 16 21 28 33 
 5  8 17 20 29 32 
 6  7 18 19 30 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if I was writing this program I would represent my data in a different manner. I.e. I would likely use a vector and avoid global size constants. The being said, here is how I would do this. Let's write out the sequence the indexes follow and try to see if we can create some kind of sequence.

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Is what is in your array after creating it and we want

```
1 6 7
2 5 8
3 4 9
```

Our indexes to the original array looks like this

```
(0, 0) (2, 1) (0, 2)
(1, 0) (1, 1) (1, 2)
(2, 0) (0, 1) (2, 2)
```

Well our j component is easy, it's just a simple arithmetic sequence where you add 1, i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
  ...
}
```

Now we need a sequence that follows the patten 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, ... repeating. Since we have repeating digits, I am thinking of clock arithmetic or modular arithmetic. Let's start with the sequence 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2 ... repeating. I.e the integers mod 3 (Z mod 3). For the first column we want the indicies straight up as they are (Z mod 3). Then for the reversed columns let's say we are given this sequence and we are iterating through it from 0 to 2. We can cleverly use modular arithmetic to get to our reversed sequence. For example if we had (2 mod 3), (4 mod 3), (6 mod 3), we would have 2, 1, 0. How do we get 0, 1, 2 to 2, 4, 6? Like this f(x) : (x + 1) * 2.

```
bool reversed = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    int idx = i;
    if(reversed){
      int offset = (i + 1) * 2;
      idx = (offset) % 3;
    }
}
reversed = !reversed;
```

Now we just have to put it all together. This should be our new init grid as the print function is fine.

```
for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
  bool reversed = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    int idx = i;
    if(reversed){
      int offset = (i + 1) * (SIZE - 1);
      idx = (offset) % SIZE;
    }
    arr[idx][j] = inc;
    inc++;
  }
  reversed = !reversed;
}
```

That should do it. I got it to work in repl.it, hopefully this helps.